# How we can store the momentjs time to PHP variable?

Tags: php, datetime, momentjs

Is it possible to save the momentjs time to PHP variable and use that variable in PHP, One way is to use ajax to send the current time on some event. So is any other best way for this ?

Comment: why not save it to cookie using jQuery but AJAX is the best option I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by passing the variable to your PHP file by whatever means you find practical ($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, etc). Ensure that you use a consistent format for the date

```
moment(yourDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY').toISOString();
```

Then use a date library in PHP to parse the date into a new date object you can then manipulate

```
$js_date = $_REQUEST['youDate'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::DATE_ATOM, $js_date);
```

You should now have a PHP variable containing a `DateTime` object called `$date`.